# calloutAccessoryControlTapped not called in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I have a view containing a MKMapView, I display sereval pins in it:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
  NSLog(@"mapView:viewForAnnotation");

  // if it's the user location, just return nil.
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
      return nil;
  }

  static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
  pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
  pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
  pinView.annotation = annotation;    

  return pinView;
}
```

This is working fine but the method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

is not called when the pin is clicked. It seems the click event is not transmitted to the pin but I cannot figure out why. Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the pin itself is clicked, the map view will call the delegate method `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`.

The `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method is called when an annotation view's `leftCalloutAccessoryView` or `rightCalloutAccessoryView` is tapped.  These are controls (usually buttons) that appear on the pin's callout.

It sounds like you are looking for the `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` delegate method instead.

Comment: Thanks Anna, you were right. On top of this I had another error in my annotation (title was empty).

Comment: Right - But the whole  bubble get the tap if both left and right accessory views are NULL